# JS- appendChild from one div object to another

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

I'm not quite sure why this code does not do what I intend it to. I have two div objects, with a series of input tags within each of them, like so:

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type....></input>
    etc,etc,etc
</div>
```

I would like to take an input tag from one, and append to the other, and then change the style of all the inputs within that div. This is what I mean :

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1").childNodes;
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2").childNodes;
div1.appendChild(div2[1]);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < div1.length; i++) {
    div1[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

I understand that whitespace is read between the tags when childNodes is used, however, I made sure that div2[1] is not whitespace. I also understand that there are other ways of doing what I am trying to do, and in fact I found other ways of doing it successfully, but I want to know why the above code, using childNodes, does not work; i.e. why none of the backgroundColors change to red.

Comment: What happen in the console if you write console.log(div2[1]) ? this may help you yo go in right direction

Comment: You have some syntax errors there, you should consult with the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN).
Also open up the developer tools in Chrome / Safari or Firefox for the detailed error

Comment: @Eyal: other than the invalid closing `</input>`, which the browser would rescue anyway, I'm not seeing any syntax errors. What have you seen that I've missed?

Comment: The error is to use div1 , a nodeList as an element. Also setting the style.backgroundColor of an element, without checking it is really an element, will cause an error and stop the javascript. Look my answer i hope it helps

Comment: @Andrea: indeed, and I've up-voted your answer for spotting that but — assuming that comment was intended for me — that's the 'error,' rather than one ('of some') syntax errors.

Comment: No no, no syntax error at all, you are right. Just misuse error of the object. i didn't understand you were pointing out that the comment before was a little bit too generic. Sorry!

Comment: @DavidThomas, I'll correct myself, There is one syntax error and some bad practices. One of the bad practices is using childNodes and not children which is inherited from the Element Object and retrieves both the HTML children and the text nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is here

div1 is not an element, is a list of nodes.
And setting style of a node without checking if it is an element will give you error.

To make it works you should do:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div1nodes = document.getElementById("div1").childNodes;
var div2nodes = document.getElementById("div2").childNodes;
div1.appendChild(div2nodes[1]);
var i, el;
for (i = 0; i < div1nodes.length; i++) {
    el = div1nodes[i];
    if (el.nodeType === 1) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

childNodes also includes text and comment nodes, so one would have to be sure that the node at div2[1] was the childnode that they wanted. Note that `childNodes` gets ALL nodes and `children` only includes element children.